# Java - Automatic connection on website with PhantomJS

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

When I use `FirefoxDriver` whith a `FirefoxProfile`, I'm automatically connected to my website but I want to use `PhantomJSDriver` for my `Selenium` tests and when I call a website with `PhantomJSDriver` I'm not automatically connected to it like with `Firefox`. This is what I used :

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
capabilities.setCapability(
    "phantomjs.binary.path",
    "lib/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe"); 
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

How can I do to automatically connect me on my website ?